# Prototype.js Interferring with Jquery UI

Tags: jquery-ui, tabs, prototypejs, lightbox

So I am currently working with an e-commerce cms that implements Lightbox to display large product pics.

In the sidebar I have implemented my own tab group powered by jquery-ui.

The sidebar works perfectly on every page except the product pages. i soon found out the problem was the call to prototype.js used by Lightbox...When i comment out the call to the prototype script the tab group starts working again.

I have tried various things like trying to change the scope of my code and reordering when the scripts are called, but this hasn't worked...any ideas on what i could do to remedy the situation?
NOTE: I didn't include any code because i thought we could just throw around soem theory : )...if you think anything would help i can add it

thanks for any help,
~skev

Comment: Did you try this? http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

Comment: @MichaelKoper i didn't think of this at first...I just tried it but nothing happened...could be that i am just implementing it wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was i needed to use $.noConflict();

before @MichealKoper suggested this i had no idea it existed

Thanks!